# Bash script using sed to append line at end of file if line doesn't exist on mac

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I need to use sed instead of echo and append to the end of a file: list.txt

list.txt has a list of directories:

/desktop/test1/file1

/desktop/test2/file1

I need to append another directory with slashes to this list.txt at the end of the file if that directory already doesn't exist in the list. Such as: /desktop/file1
The result should be:

/desktop/test1/file1

/desktop/test2/file1

/desktop/file1

I've tried using this script but am running into syntax errors with the a command which I've been seeing could be a mac issue?:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q "/desktop/file1" user/admin/Desktop/list.txt; then
    sed -i -e '$a/desktop/file1' user/admin/Desktop/list.txt
fi
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `sed` instead of `echo`?  It's not unreasonable to use `grep` and `echo`, but it would be better to use `awk` than `sed`.

Comment: the program I'm running needs sed, I'm not familiar with awk but if there's a solution with that I'd be happy to hear it

Comment: For simplicity, I would just replace your `sed` with `echo "$path" >> "$file"` and move on.

Comment: As I stated in the first line of my question, I need to use sed instead of echo.

Comment: I generally strongly oppose the use of `-i` (and you haven't explained why you can't use `echo`, which is absolutely the right tool), but the issue you're having is simply that the sed syntax requires a literal newline after the `a`.  If you're using bash, you can do: `sed -i -e $'$a\\\n/desktop/file1' path`

Comment: mac has `ed` by default so:  `printf '%s\n' '$a'  '/desktop/file1' . ,p w | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: Why can't you use echo?

Answer (score 0):

The `a` command is used as `a\` in standard `sed` and should be followed by a newline and the text to be written. The form you use is a GNU extension. So a standard `sed` command to do the job could be:

```
sed -i '' '$a\
/desktop/file1' user/admin/Desktop/list.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '' '$a\'$'\n''/desktop/file1' user/admin/Desktop/list.txt
```

using ANSI-C quoting in bash.

Comment: Plus on the OS X version of `sed`, the `-i` option requires an argument.

Comment: how would I add an argument? I don't need a backup file

Comment: @jeeter592 What do you mean by *argument* ? Doesn't replacing your `sed` command with mine work?